# How to add file with custom extension to bundle/resource folder in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, file-extension

I have a problem. I have been made a file with custom extension like .xyz in resource folder. But when I running the application, the file wasn't in resource folder. How can I add the file with custom extension? Anybody can help me?

Thanks before. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that this .xyz file is in the Copy Resources phase of your application's target.

Answer (score 1):

simple drag n drop to your resources folder and check copy items to resources folder option. That's it.

Comment: If we only do that, the file would not appear in application. I add new file in XCode. I choose empty file and give extension .xyz. That appears in XCode but no in application. Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with "the file wasn't in resource folder" ?
do you want to move it into `Documents` directory ?
if yes, you just can move your file from `resource` into `Documents`, i was do something like that with this code :

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:documentsPath error:NULL];
```